# undefined method `post' for RSpec when processing emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, post, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a test where an email posts to a route, and is then processed as it would normally be.  I am getting the above error from this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature 'send email', %q{
} , :js => true do

    before(:each) do 
        sign_in
        @email = build(:email, :with_attachment)
    end

    scenario 'Email works' do
        post "/email_processor", @email
        sleep
    end
end
```

I am using Capybara, Selenium, and Rspec.  Any help/clues would be much appreciated, as nothing I've found so far has been any help to me

Comment: Confused a little bit. `:js => true` means you want to run the test in the browser, so this is to be a feature test. In feature tests you can visit pages, but not send post request. Visit the page which has a link/form and click appropriate button.

Comment: @BroiSatse I actually didnt know that so thanks, but what I'm trying to do is test the emailing aspect of this site.  I receive an email with an attachment specific to this site and the site processes it all and displays stats on the attachment.  I want to be able to fake an email so that I can look at the page where the parsed data is and see it all, do you know how I would do this?

Comment: Are you trying to test a POST request from inside an HTML email? This is bad practice and email clients will most likely disable the form from which you can post or treat it as a vulnerability.